How to determine if a curve is closed and simple
The purpose of this post (as a complient to How to determine if the curve is closed) is to shed some additional light on the best way to proceed with analyzing if a particular curve is closed, simple, and related issues of interest. I know from the definition that a curve is closed when start and end points coinside.
For example, I have the following problem where: the curve $\gamma$ is given by
$$
\gamma = (1 + \cos 2t, \sin 2t, 2 \sin t), -\pi \leq t \leq \pi
$$
Is $\gamma$
i) Closed? Simple?
ii) on surface $x^2 + y^2 +z^2 = 4$?
iii) on surface $(x-1)^2 +y^2 = 1$?
iiii) Describe or draw the curve.
I simply proceed with plugging in the values of t
$$
\gamma(-\pi) = (1+\cos(-2\pi), \sin(-2\pi), 2 \sin(-\pi)) = (0,0,0)
$$
$$
\gamma(\pi) = (1+\cos(2\pi), \sin(2\pi), 2 \sin(\pi)) = (2,0,0)
$$
Hence $\gamma(-\pi) \neq \gamma(\pi)$. So what am I missing, and how to proceed with checking if a curve is simple or not?
And secondly, any tips for analysing if a curve is on a particular surface? Any clarifications is highly appreciated. Thanks.
Sincerely,
TS

Hello. What is the definition of a simple curve ? Recalling definitions often provides a way to see the method to use in answering a question. To see if a curve is on a surface, just check that the points of the curve satisfy the equation of the surface.

A simple curve doesn't intersect itself.

if your curve is simple, then the map $\gamma:[-\pi,\pi]\rightarrow\Bbb R^3$ is injective. You can check this component-wise, if you're a little careful.

But I still haven't showd it's closed? Since $\gamma(-\pi) \neq \gamma(\pi)$, what am I missing? Thx.
